# Regex only validates some date of births

Tags: regex, validation

In my assignment for a class, I am trying to validate a textbox used for data of birth using regex. For some reason, only some date of births are being validated. I will provide a screenshot from https://regexr.com/.  I have tried many solutions, like pasting other people's solutions from this website, but I am not having any luck.

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1RIi.png)

Here is the expression: `(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)?\d\d`

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to validate  the whole string? `^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)?\d\d$`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes, I do. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey, your regex satisfies the dd/mm/yy format, you can change the first and second groups to make it work for the given cases

Answer (score 1):

The regex in the image seems to be for international date format while the dates are either invalid or in the US date format

Comment: Looking for a US date format seemed to work. Thanks.

Comment: here's a good resource to learn more about regex https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DG3kCDx53c